# Automatic regional classification

Tags: python, django, design-patterns

I am scraping stories from several news agencies and I would like to create a filter to automatically classify the stories.

I now have a table in my database containing all the countries of the world and a related table containing their cities.

So I am very confused now on how to tackle this one. The only solution I can think of is to split the story words and then compare every word to every country and city which will consume a huge amount of resource I believe.

Please advice.

Comment: Are you trying to extract location features? Or you're trying to assign label to stories. If you're trying to assign labels you can use [nltk](http://nltk.org/). If you're trying to extract some part you might want to use regular expressions.

Comment: how about you divide it by group, by continent or in other way which consume small amount of resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that searching the story until you find a city would be as highly inefficient as it might seem for a world news article. I just took a look at the [BBC World News homepage](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world/), the majority of the cities are mentioned in the first paragraph. If I claimed any sort of insight from this I would probably make Statisticians cry but I have a hunch this may be true for most world news sights.

Unfortunately I'm not versed in Python but here's a C# program that would achieve this.

```
class Program
{
    //You could have 2 Hashsets, one for cities and one for countries and find both but you can always derive a country from a city so you won't need as much memory to reduce the load factor of the hash table. 
    //However this does mean if an article mentions only a country and not a city you can't categorize it.
    static HashSet<String> cities = new HashSet<String>();
    static Dictionary<String, String> cityToCountry = new Dictionary<String, String>();
    const int MAX_WORDS_TO_READ = 200;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        addCities();
        String sentance = "Former South African President Nelson Mandela is discharged from hospital in Johannesburg after 10 days of treatment for pneumonia.";

        String city = findCity(sentance);
        String country = cityToCountry[city];

        Console.WriteLine(city + ", " + country);
        Console.ReadLine();


    }

    static String findCity(String sentance)
    {

        String word = "";
        int wordsSeen = 0;

        foreach (char c in sentance)
        {
            if (c != ' ')
            {
                word += c;
            }
            else
            {
                if (isCity(word))
                {
                    return word;
                }
                else
                {
                    word = "";
                }

                wordsSeen++;
            }

            //If you assume that if the city is not in the first n words then the article isn't about a specific city or one that you don't have in your database
            //then you can avoid having to check through massive articles that have no city
            if(wordsSeen > MAX_WORDS_TO_READ)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    static bool isCity(String city)
    {
        return cities.Contains(city);
    }


    static void addCities()
    {
        //Naturally you would parse in a list of cities from somewhere
        cities.Add("Berlin");
        cities.Add("London");
        cities.Add("Johannesburg");

        cityToCountry.Add("Berlin", "Germany");
        cityToCountry.Add("London", "England");
        cityToCountry.Add("Johannesburg", "South Africa");
    }




}
```

On the other hand if you take a look at BBC News England section then you end up with [stories like this](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-devon-22054634), which doesn't even mention the country in the article itself and if your list of cities contains Okehampton I'd be highly suprised. To resolve this issue you could to use context given by the section of the news site that the story is in but the bottom line is that how efficient this method is will depend on the type of news stories you are scraping.